# $\lim_{t \to \infty} t\mu(f > t) = 0$ but $f \not \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> I have the following question: Give a non-negative lebesgue measurable function $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that

> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{t \to \infty} t\mu(f > t) = 0
> \end{equation}

> but $f \not \in L^1$

In a previous part of a problem, I was able to show that $f \in L^1$ is a sufficient condition for the limit to be $0$. I have tried stuff like $1/x$ which is not in $L^1$ but the limit is $1$ in this case. I have tried other variations like $1/x^n$ where $n \geq 0$ but none of these work.

I think that $[0,1]$ having finite measure is likely relevant, but don't know how.

Comment: From basic Probability Theory there exists $f$ such that $\mu (f>t)=\frac 1 {t \ln t}$ for $t \geq 2$. This $f$ satisfies your requirements.

Comment: HInt:  the line between integrable and non-integrable for $1/x^p$ is $p=1.$ So you need to squeeze a function in between. So, maybe a $\log$ of some kind? Well,  just saw that the other comment gave it away. I will leave mine though because it may indicate the thinking on how the function is obtained.